# How to launch an RCP application from windows Run dialog?

Tags: windows, registry, eclipse-rcp, rcp, regedit

I have an Eclipse RCP application which I need to launch from Windows Run dialog.

I tried it by setting a key in REGISTERY entry in

```
HKLM\SOFTWARES\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\All Paths\**full path to exe**
```

but the app was not launching. How can I launch an RCP application from the RUN dialog?

File hierarchy in the folder:

[image: File hierarchy in folder]

Entry in registry(app name Hello.exe:

[image: Entry in registry(app name Hello.exe)]

The exe is not loading because in the .ini file endorsed folder is specified to take from the current location (./endorsed). How can I tell the machine to load jars from an endorsed folder?
One approach I found to be working is that to modify the .ini file at run time, so we can specify the full path for the endorsed folder while run time. But is that a good design?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use registry entries. Rather specify the full path.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, but I tried using full path only.